# Python 3.x - Extract string from data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume a dataframe df -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['a'])
```

I want to extract the string 'a' from this dataframe. I tried to extract it by trying the following from stackoverflow answers - 
 Attempt 1 -

```
print(df.iloc[0])
>>0    a
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Attempt 2 -

```
print(df.astype(str))
>>  0
0  a
```

Please help me extract the string 'a' from the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) you getting the first series from dataframe. If you want first element of that series you should use it twice or with `iloc[0][0]`:

```
In [57]: df.iloc[0][0]
Out[57]: 'a'

In [58]: df.iloc[0].iloc[0]
Out[58]: 'a'
```